Can a Knowledge License be assigned by Permission Set instead of the "Knowledge User" checkbox on the User Record?
I'm trying to integrate a user provisioning service between Sailpoint and Salesforce. The field on the User record which sets the Knowledge License  (i.e. "UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser") on the User record is not an option to be set during provisioning.
Similarly, UserPermissionsInteractionUser (Flow User) is also something not available during provisioning, but this can be set using the "Run Flows" permission in a permission set.
Can the Knowledge User license be set with a permission set?

Why down-voted? This traiblazer page says "Flow User" can be set via Permission Set. Can Knowledge User be set? Everything I tried wouldn't work, but figured I'd ask the community. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000FSdXtSAL
